# counter off by one in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I have a counter incrementor in react-native using useState.Whenever I press a button the count should increase by one. it works fine however when first press happens the counter is still 0 when the second press happens the counter increases by one and continues smoothly with no problem. Why isn't it updating on the first press? here is code:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, {useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [outputState, setOutputState] = useState(`You have tapped ${count} times`);

  const getFinalResult = () => {
    setCount(count => count + 1);
    setOutputState(`You have tapped ${count} times`);
    
  }
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{outputState}</Text>
      <Button title="change text" onPress={getFinalResult} />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work for you. You was setting the state and displaying at the same time. Setting State is async task and it required some time to complete.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, {useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>You have tapped {count} times</Text>
      <Button title="change text" onPress={() => setCount(count => count + 1)} />
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```